# uitablleview crashes when link datasource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, asihttprequest

I am calling a view that contains a tableview and is showed properly until I link datsource to file's owner and generates following SIGABRT error.
I do not understand what is happening because I had set tableview in other views and works! Problem is same as this thread because I am also using ASIHttprequest:

[SIGABRT on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155542/sigabrt-on-startup)

```
 2011-10-13 00:53:36.633 Nimbo[1713:207] -[testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c6fa30
    2011-10-13 00:53:36.639 Nimbo[1713:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c6fa30'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
```

Comment: You might want to provide some code as well...

Comment: one of those questions where i'm sad i cannot downvote yet, this shows no research effort at all, and the asker even seems to ignore XCode compiler warnings ... they are there for a reason and in this case should almost exactly tell you what to do ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you implemented this method in you viewController:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Because you are missing this required Delegate method view controller conformed to UITableViewDataSource protocol calls required method on your class since you havent implemented it it crashed.
When you compiled your code likely you have gotten this as warning that you havent conformed to this protocol

Answer (score 0):

Your `testViewController` doesnt have a method called `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` but somewhere in your code `[testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:];` is being called.  Please post the code where you are using `testViewController`.

---

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> ```
> - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
> ```
>
> Returns the number of rows (table cells) in a
>   specified section.
>
> **Parameters** 
>   `section` - An index number that identifies a section of the table. Table views in a plain style have a section index of zero.
>
> **Return Value**
>    The number of rows in the section.
>
> UITableView gets the value returned by this method from its data source and caches it.

Comment: no he is not using this somewhere in hos code, the tableview is calling it on his datasouce

Comment: @Ahti semantics... the point was that the method was being called on an object that did not have that method defined.